# Storing a max of 6 cards per page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am making a pokedex API. I am now able to load all the cards by name or type. But the code loads in all the cards at one page. I would like to store the cards with a max of 6 and then they continue on a new page. But I can't find how to do this so if anyone has an idea let me know!

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {

$("#TheSubmitButton").on("click", function(event){

  $("#card-container").empty();
  event.preventDefault();
  var pokemon = $("#searchInput").val().trim();

  $.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=name:" + pokemon

  }).then(function(response){
    for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {

      var pokeTainer = $("<div class='poketainer'></div>");

      var pokemonName = $("<div></div>");
      pokemonName.text(response.data[i].name);
      pokeTainer.append(pokemonName);

      var pokemonCard = $("<img class='pkmn-card'>");
      pokemonCard.attr("src", response.data[i].images.small);
      pokeTainer.append(pokemonCard);
                  
      var pokemonEvolve = $("<div></div>");
      pokemonEvolve.text('Evolves to: ' + response.data[i].evolvesTo);
      pokeTainer.append(pokemonEvolve);
                  
      var pokemonFlavor = $("<div></div>");
      pokemonFlavor.text(response.data[i].flavorText);
      pokeTainer.append(pokemonFlavor);

      var pokemonTypes = $("<div></div>");
      pokemonTypes.text(response.data[i].types);
      pokeTainer.append(pokemonTypes);
                  
      $("#card-container").append(pokeTainer);
        
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Does the API support paging parameters?

Comment: I think it does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very basic snippet (including pagination):

```js
const page = document.getElementById('card-container')

// the funcftion that fetches data from the API
const fetchData = ({
  name,
  pageNumber
}) => {
  return fetch(`https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=name:${name}&page=${pageNumber}&pageSize=6`)
}

// constructing the HTML, based on the
// JSON returned from the API
const pageHtml = ({
  data
}) => {
  let html = ''
  data.forEach(pokemon => {
    html += '<div>'
    html += `<div>${pokemon.name}</div>`
    html += `<div><img src="${pokemon.images.small}" /></div>`
    if (pokemon.evolvesTo) {
      html += `<div>Evolves to: ${pokemon.evolvesTo}</div>`
    }
    if (pokemon.evolvesFrom) {
      html += `<div>Evolves from: ${pokemon.evolvesFrom}</div>`
    }
    html += `<div>${pokemon.flavorText}</div>`
    html += `<div>${pokemon.types}</div>`
    html += '</div><hr />'
  })
  return html
}

// the update function:
// fetching & then updating the view
const updatePage = (searchObj) => {
  fetchData({ ...searchObj
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(json => {
      page.innerHTML = pageHtml(json)
    })
}

// basic search parameters
let searchObj = {
  name: '',
  pageNumber: 1,
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // updating the name search parameter
  $('#searchInput').on('input', function(e) {
    searchObj = {
      ...searchObj,
      name: $(this).val().trim()
    }
  })

  // submitting the query, based on the current
  // search parameters
  $('#TheSubmitButton').on('click', function(e) {
    updatePage(searchObj)
  })

  // previous page
  // NOT PROTECTED FROM overflow
  $('#prevPage').on('click', function() {
    searchObj = {
      ...searchObj,
      pageNumber: searchObj.pageNumber - 1
    }

    updatePage(searchObj)
  })
 
  // next page
  // NOT PROTECTED FROM overflow
  $('#nextPage').on('click', function() {
    searchObj = {
      ...searchObj,
      pageNumber: searchObj.pageNumber + 1
    }

    updatePage(searchObj)
  })
  
})
```

```css
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  width: 30%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="POKEMON NAME" /><br />
  <button id="TheSubmitButton">SEARCH</button>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <button id="prevPage">PREV</button>
  <button id="nextPage">NEXT</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div id="card-container"></div>
```

- the search parameters are kept in a parameter object (so you can easily extend it to `maxNumPages`, `hasPrev`, `hasNext`, etc.)
- the fetch function is extracted, so you just have to pass in parameters & it fetches the data
- the HTML is created in a separate function (like a template, that you can easily modify)
- the pagination (prev page, next page) is NOT OK, as it allows going before the first page or after the last page

Comment: Made some [improvements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69800109/1762224).

Answer (score 0):

Change your API url to this:

```
url: "https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=name:" + pokemon + "&page=" + pageNumber + "&pageSize=6"
```

Source: [Documentation](https://docs.pokemontcg.io/api-reference/cards/search-cards)

Answer (score 0):

Store your API data to LocalStorage and pull data to show in UI when user scroll it.

OR
Store Array of objects with pages.
ex:

```
[
   {
     page: 1,
     data: [ 6 records here.]
   },
   {
     page: 2,
     data: [ 6 records here.]
   }
]
```

and then show on UI when user scrolls it.

ie - separate the html creation as different function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improved version of [muka.gergely's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69798950/1762224). I removed the jQuery dependency and utilized the paging information from the response to disable the buttons to prevent over-paging. I also reset the page, upon querying for a new Pokémon.

```js
const
  results = document.querySelector('.results'),
  searchInput = document.querySelector('#searchInput'),
  submitButton = document.querySelector('#TheSubmitButton'),
  prevPageButton = document.querySelector('#prevPage'),
  nextPageButton = document.querySelector('#nextPage');

const fetchData = ({ name, page, pageSize = 6 }) =>
  fetch(`https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards?q=name:${name}&page=${page}&pageSize=${pageSize}`);

const pageHtml = (data) =>
  data.map(pokemon => `
    <div class="card">
      <div class="title">${pokemon.name}</div>
      <div><img src="${pokemon.images.small}" /></div>
      ${pokemon.evolvesTo ? `<div>Evolves into: ${pokemon.evolvesTo}</div>` : ''}
      ${pokemon.evolvesFrom ? `<div>Evolves from: ${pokemon.evolvesFrom}</div>` : ''}
      ${pokemon.flavorText ? `<div class="flavor">${pokemon.flavorText}</div>` : ''}
      <div>${pokemon.types}</div>
    </div>
  `).join('')

let state = { name: '', page: 1 }

const updatePage = () =>
  fetchData({ ...state })
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(({ count, data, page, pageSize, totalCount }) => {
      results.innerHTML = pageHtml(data);
      state = { ...state, count, page, pageSize, totalCount };
      prevPageButton.disabled = state.page === 1;
      nextPageButton.disabled = state.count < state.pageSize;
    })

const handleSearch = (e) => {
  state = { ...state, name: e.target.value.trim(), page: 1 };
};

const handleSubmit = () => updatePage(state);

const handlePrev = () => {
  state = { ...state, page: state.page - 1 };
  updatePage();
};

const handleNext = () => {
  state = { ...state, page: state.page + 1 };
  updatePage();
}; 

searchInput.addEventListener('input', handleSearch);
submitButton.addEventListener('click', handleSubmit);
prevPageButton.addEventListener('click', handlePrev);
nextPageButton.addEventListener('click', handleNext);
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.search {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.results {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: thin solid grey;
  margin: 0.25em;
  padding: 0.5em;
  flex: 1;
}

.card img {
  width: 180px;
  height: 240px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flavor {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Pokémon name..." />
  <button id="TheSubmitButton">Search</button>
</div>
<div class="pagination">
  <button id="prevPage">Prev</button>
  <button id="nextPage">Next</button>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="results"></div>
```